# VS2017 Scanning data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I opened a solution in VS2017 and noticed the below image stating "Scanning data XX%"

[image]

Does anyone know what VS is doing here? It seems to be taking a long time for a solution with 9 projects one of which is a .net core angular2 app.

Comment: I have found some related post [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3867/folder-scanning-gets-stuck.html)

Comment: what is the Solution @Animal Style

Answer (score 7):

It seems that if you invoke the 'Folder View' capability from the solution explorer, it starts to scan mysterious data (the folder structure I assume). Reason is not known.

However, following [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55157/mysterious-scanning-data-caption-and-progress-indi.html), I assume that Microsoft will fix this in the future release.

I did not find *Scanning Data* hinder any of my work, though it may slow down the PC a bit.

[image: Folder or Solution View]

Comment: what's the Solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you opened the project as a "Folder", which will need to find and catalog all the files within the folder structure, including the massive "node_modules".

I "fixed" this by opening as "Web Site".

[image: Open As Website]

Comment: I did not open the project as a folder since it is an asp.net core project that is hosting my angular app.

Comment: Yep, this helps

Answer (score 1):

OK i think i have found the solution
[image: VS 2017 install]
**During installation pls uncheck the c++ things it can cause you trouble in cloning or  Data scanning**

Comment: This could be correct but I am not going to uninstall/reinstall VS2017 to test it out. Thanks for the answer though and I will keep this in mind if I do have to install it again.