# trying to clone in GIT from TFS and it stuckes after 27 % while data scanning in Visual studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs, visual-studio-2017

> i am trying to clone in GIT from TFS and it stuckes after 27 % while
>   data scanning using Git for the 1st time it's keep on happening again
>   and again i have even changed Directory location again and again but
>   no result. using VS 2017 !!
>   disk space =6.73GB still left(no memory issue even after Cloning)
>   [image: TFS]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2017 Scanning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845879/vs2017-scanning-data)

Comment: @max630 solution is not written

Comment: Are there any messages in the output windows? I ran into a similar issue but hard to know without any messages. Here&#39;s the link. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html?childToView=81636

Comment: If you verified that no solution file is yet written to the clone folder while you are seeing this message then it makes sense to add it to the question.

Comment: @MikeDouglasDev mine is cloning but unable to move fwd. in data scanning after 27%?

Comment: i have found the Solution posted here [Possible Solution to the Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261678/8080496)